# how to create a txt file with specific information in c++

Tags: c++

my goal is to create a .txt file like this:

---

598.1       # temperature in Kelvin

3.49       # pressure in atm

H_g        # list of species allowed in the system

H2_ref

---

but, the first 2 values should be 2 double values, which i am using in my program

i'am using c++

If anyone has got a solution or hints for me?

That would be awesome!

Thank you in advance!

best regards

schwing

Comment: Read up on iostreams and printf.

Comment: So "with specific information" opposes "with random information", which is supposedly the default way text files are written?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

This should write your double to a text file. For more information read http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

```
// basic file operations
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void writeFile() {
    double myTempInK = 0;
    double myPresInAtm = 0;

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("example.txt");
    myfile << myTempInK << "# temperature in Kelvin\n";
    myfile << myPresInAtm << "# pressure in atm\n";
    myfile << "H_g # list of species allowed in the system\n";
    myfile << "H2_ref \n";
    myfile.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert data and create the file use `std::ifstream f;` and open it then write to it using `f.write(...);`

Answer (score 0):

@FreshD and Graham Best: 
thanks a lot...now it is working properly with this code:

```
std::ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("C:/Users/schwing/temp/example.txt");
myfile << p << "\n " << T << "asdf";
myfile.close();
```

just one question is left:
i had to specify the exact file directory. Where is the program puting the file, if i'm not using C:/Users/schwing.... and is there a possibility to use "relative" paths?

i have to mention, that i am generating a dll, and running the program in another program!

thanks in advance!